# Django migrations not working with multiple apps

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have created a project with django which has 2 apps. Each of them has a models.py that I will show below. The problem occurs when I try to launch:

```
python manage.py makemigratios
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pablo/.local/share/virtualenvs/portfolio-cTVCjELO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: no existe la relación «weatherapi_weatherstation»
LINE 1: ...gitude", "weatherapi_weatherstation"."token" FROM "weatherap...
```

...

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «weatherapi_weatherstation»
LINE 1: ...gitude", "weatherapi_weatherstation"."token" FROM "weatherap...
                                                         ^
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

They are two very simple models and everything seems to be correct but it is impossible to launch makemigrations. I have also tried to drop the DB but it is still the same.

**Settings.py**

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'portfolio',
            'USER': 'pablo',
            'PASSWORD': '1234',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

**Models 1:**

```
from uuid import uuid1
from django.db import models


def generate_uid():
    return uuid1().hex


# Create your models here.
class WeatherStation(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True, default=generate_uid)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="No name")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    token = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WeatherRecord(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    temperature = models.DecimalField(default=None, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    humidity = models.DecimalField(default=None, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    pressure = models.DecimalField(default=None, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weather_station = models.ForeignKey(WeatherStation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

**Models 2:**

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Título')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name='Contenido')
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name='Fecha de publicación')
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen', upload_to='blog', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Autor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Categorias', related_name="get_posts")
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Try using `python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME` on both of them and see what comes back

Comment: It doesn't work either but I have found the problem. It is a query in forms.py. There shouldn't be an implicit query there and that makes the migrations fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:
The problem was in the forms.py file there was an implicit query which should not be put there. Because of this it was not possible to do the migrations. When I removed that query everything worked again.